# Extracting text pattern using regular expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to extract a code from an input string from different pages. Sample code is 
'110-PT-0988'.

This RegExp fits other possible cases `'^\d{3}-[A-Z]{1,6}-\d{4}[A-Z]{0,2}$'`.

I want to return a string variable containing the code within the input string e.g. for an input string

`'Code part: xx Code No: 120-PXT-2234X System Process .....xyz blah blah'.`

I want the return string to be `'120-PXT-2234X'`

Comment: @nhahtdh: the language is called 'Regular Expression'.

Comment: @arkascha: I'm asking about the programming language. The regex can be modified a bit, but the programming construct/function is also necessary to make a sensible answer.

Comment: @arkascha, NO it is not. Regular expressions are always part of a programming language or tool and everywhere they are different.

Comment: Actually Regular Expressions are not part of a programming language. They are very well defined, it is only the implementations that do not follow that definition sometimes.

Comment: @arkascha, please show us that definition and please do not come up with regular languages from language theory, that has not much to do with what is used nowadays in programming as "regular expression". And I can't agree with "*it is only the implementations that do not follow that definition sometimes*". There are huge differences between the programming languages on the regular expression features they do support, therefore the programming language tag is needed for every regex question, [see the regex FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: @stema Oh, I see... "the differences between programming languages on the regular expressions" is _not_ an implementation issue? Good to have learned that...

Comment: @arkascha, off course this is an "implementation issue". What I want to say is, there is not something like a regular expressions standard.

Answer (score 3):

The problem are the [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$`. They match the start and the end of the string and since your pattern is in the middle of a string, it will not find it.

The anchor `\b` for a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), would be a better choice here, try

```
\b\d{3}-[A-Z]{1,6}-\d{4}[A-Z]{0,2}\b#
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32cr8)

Comment: @OyedeleDamilare, I added the tag and my answer is fine for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match such a pattern within a larger string, then you need to remove the anchors (`^` and `$`):

```
\d{3}-[A-Z]{1,6}-\d{4}[A-Z]{0,2}
```

That way the regex matches any *substring* that matches the pattern.

Comment: A million thanks. I got it working now.This is the sample code:

Dim strText, strPattern as string
dim m as Match = Regex.Match(strText,strPattern)
lblResult.Text = (m.Groups(0).Value)

Example: strText = "Sys Code Num:. 172-PI-9978 This is just sample"
strPattern = "\d{3}-[A-Z]{1,6}-\d{4}[A-Z]{0,2}"

This returns 172-PI-9978 in the lblResult Label.
Once again thanks for your suggestion